# .dockerignore all subfolders but not files in the folder itself

Tags: git, docker

I've got a folder structure like below. I want to ignore all subfolders (and all their content) of `.git` but include all files which are directly in `.git` (e.g. FETCH_HEAD and HEAD).

How do I write that in the `.dockerignore` file.

```
.git
├── COMMIT_EDITMSG
├── FETCH_HEAD
├── HEAD
├── description
├── hooks
│   ├── applypatch-msg.sample
│   ├── commit-msg.sample
│   ├── post-update.sample
│   ├── pre-applypatch.sample
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/dockerignore-file) you can ignore only subdirectories:

```
.git/*/*
```

You don't have to manually exclude files which are directly in `.git` directory.

Comment: This still creates the sub-directories but they are empty which is ok in my case :)

Answer (score 2):

Since docker 1.7, a [`.dockerignore` file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/dockerignore-file) supports exception:

```
*/*
!FETCH_HEAD
!HEAD
```

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to exclude files to ignore with `!`.

```
.git/*/
!.git/HEAD
!.git/FETCH_HEAD
```